# Post command not writing to database with BubbleWrap

Tags: rest, rubymotion

I currently have an iOS app i'm creating with Rubymotion. I am using Bubblewrap to do my REST commands. I have the below code, and it is creating the record, but not writing any of the data.

```
first = @kidfirst.text
last = @kidlast.text
data = {first_name: '#{first}', last_name: '#{last}'}
BW::HTTP.post("url", {payload: data}) do |response|
  if response.ok?
    p "Success"
  else
    p "response.error_message"
  end
end
```

I am getting the "Success" response also. What would stop it from posting the data to my application but create the account?

Comment: Can you show us the HTTP POST-request handler?

Comment: Dumb question, but how do I call that with Rubymotion?

Comment: I'm not a Rubymotion expert but with a little read from documentation, it seems that you are making a HTTP POST-request to address "url" with the request body having your JSON-data {}. I assume "url" is just a placeholder text; you must have a valid URL you are posting your data and an HTTP server listening for those POSTs at that URL. If you don't have a clue what I'm talking about, you need to learn more HTTP or I'm clueless about Rubymotion :)

Comment: I get what you're saying. I know it's listening for the HTTP requests because it creates the object in my database, just no data in it. i.e id:1 first_name:nil last_name:nil So after I send the post it shows an empty object on my screen. I don't know why my data isn't being passed. I assume(correct me if i'm wrong) that if the HTTP server is pulling get requests then it should be successfully doing POST's also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first = @kidfirst.text
last = @kidlast.text
data = {:child => {first_name: '#{first}', last_name: '#{last}'}}
BW::HTTP.post("url", {payload: data}) do |response|
  if response.ok?
    p "Success"
  else
    p "response.error_message"
  end
end
```

The issue was when it went to post it didn't know where to post it on the rails backend because I was calling params[:child].